# Is there a variation of the within transformation that can account for individual-specific interactions with time-fixed effects?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, interaction, panel-data

If we're studying a population over time where each individual is subject to the same time-varying intercept, we can model it with time-fixed effects (ignoring any individual-fixed effects):
$$
Y_{it} = X_{it}\beta + \alpha_t + \epsilon_{it}\,.
$$

We can then form a within(-time) transformation by subtracting the mean (across individuals) of each side to remove the time-fixed effects like so:
$$
\begin{align}
Y_{it}-\bar{Y}_t &= (X_{it}-\bar{X}_t)\beta + \underbrace{(\alpha_t-\bar{\alpha}_t)}_{= \ 0} + (\epsilon_{it}-\bar\epsilon_t) \\
&=(X_{it}-\bar{X}_t)\beta + \epsilon'_{it}\,.
\end{align}
$$

But if each individual has a different interaction ($\gamma_i$ below) with the time-varying intercept like this,
$$
Y_{it} = X_{it}\beta + \gamma_i \alpha_t + \epsilon_{it}\,,
$$

the standard transform leaves us with time-fixed effects with individual interactions, which is unacceptable:

$$
Y_{it}-\bar{Y}_t = (X_{it}-\bar{X}_t)\beta + \underbrace{(\gamma_i-\bar{\gamma})\alpha_t }_{\neq \ 0} + (\epsilon_{it}-\bar\epsilon_t) \,.
$$

The next naive thought to subtract the gamma-weighted mean (which we can't even do without knowing the gamma terms beforehand) leaves us the same problem:
$$
Y_{it}-\sum_i\frac{\gamma_i}{N\bar\gamma} Y_{it} = (X_{it}-\sum_i\frac{\gamma_i}{N\bar\gamma} X_{it})\beta + \underbrace{(\gamma_i-\sum_i\frac{\gamma_i^2}{N\bar\gamma})\alpha_t }_{\neq \ 0} + (\epsilon_{it}-\sum_i\frac{\gamma_i}{N\bar\gamma}\epsilon_{it}) \,.
$$

Is there any straightforward/"standard" transformation we can do to remove the time-fixed effects *with interactions*?

My only real thought here is that this looks like a factor model with a single latent factor. Would we have to do something like iteratively fit a factor model and fit a linear model to the residuals?

Comment: This seems like the type of situation handled by mixed models or generalized least squares. Have you considered those approaches? See Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long.html).